# js: the environment was captured during function creation. How can I overcome this?

Tags: javascript, closures, geocoding

I'm running the following script that does geocoding:

```
function find_callback(response){

        var map = g_waze_map.map;
        var first_result = response[0];

        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(first_result.location.lon,first_result.location.lat);

        g_waze_map.map.setCenter(lonlat);

        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(36,47);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.waze.co.il/images/home.png',size,offset);

        var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
        map.addLayer(markers);
        markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat,icon));

        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("test",lonlat,null,
                        "<div style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:0.8em;'>"+first_result.name+"<div>",
                        anchor=null,true,null));
    };
```

When I invoke the 3 calls to "find" in a batch (as part of my JS) I get a map with only the 3rd piont on it. When I invoke them via chrome console (one by one) I get a map with all 3 point on it. Is it the call_back that holds its environment? If so, how can I overcome this?

```
function onInit(){

            g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[2]%>','find_callback');
            g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[3]%>','find_callback');
            g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[5]%>','find_callback');

}
```

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I think you need to declare "markers"outside the function to make it global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work-around was: sending an array of location to the  g_waze_map.find();
That achived my goal, but I yet don't understand why it didn't work in the original way.

Answer (score 0):

This script looks very strange to me. I'm assuming you only have one `map` object (`g_waze_map.map`) but for each callback you do `g_waze_map.map.setCenter(lonlat);` where `lonlat` is the latitude longitude of the first result. That doesn't make any sense.

If you calls to `g_waze_map.find` are asynchronous then you don't know what order they will finish in so I have no idea why you'd want to `setCenter`.

Also, why not just:

```
        g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[2]%>', find_callback);
        g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[3]%>', find_callback);
        g_waze_map.find('<%#Locations[5]%>', find_callback);
        // without the quotes, find_callback is a function afterall
```

Comment: at any rate it doesn't explain why it works via browser console and not in a batch.